# Adding Number Result in NaN

Tags: javascript, html, nan

```html
<script>
function myFunction(val) {
    const ele = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    let sum = 0;
    ele.forEach(input => {
        sum += input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
    });
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = sum.toFixed(2);
}
</script>

<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="array[]" class="input" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
<input type="text" id="array[]" class="input" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
<p id="result"></p>
<br>
<p><input type="submit" name= "submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></p>

</form>
```

Why the result is NaN? But if I remove the value="Submit" in the last 5th line, then everything working fine. Why? and what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: because you are selecting all the input tag, you should be specific on selecting like  querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'). so it will select only text input tags. Try this one

Comment: @ Jt Tan, cool happy to help kindly accept if it worked for you :)

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type=submit])')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
const ele = document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

will iterate over *all* inputs, including the `<input type="submit" name= "submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>`.

When you don't use `value="Submit"`, that element doesn't have a real `.value`, so it defaults to the empty string:

```js
console.log(submit.value);
console.log(submit.value.length);
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

In contrast, `<input value="Submit"/>` will have a `.value` of `Submit`, which can't be turned into a number.

Select only your inputs with `input` classes instead:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ele = document.querySelectorAll('input.input');
  let sum = 0;
  ele.forEach(input => {
    sum += input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
  });
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = sum.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="text" id="array[]" class="input" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
  <input type="text" id="array[]" class="input" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
  <p id="result"></p>
  <br>
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
```

Also note that duplicate IDs are invalid HTML, and event handlers should be attached properly using Javascript instead of using inline handlers:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.input');
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
    const sum = [...inputs].reduce((a, input) => a + Number(input.value), 0);
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = sum.toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="text" class="input">
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <p id="result"></p>
  <br>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are selecting all the input tag, you should be specific on selecting like `querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')`. so it will select only text input tags. Try this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

function myFunction(val) {
    const ele = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    let sum = 0;
    ele.forEach(input => {

        sum += input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
    });
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = sum.toFixed(2);
}
</script>


<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="array[]" class="input" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
<input type="text" id="array[]" class="input" oninput="myFunction(this.value)">
<p id="result"></p>
<br>
<p><input type="submit" name= "submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.querySelectorAll('input');` selecting all inputs including submit button as well which has value='submit' and value `submit` is not a number (NAN). When you remove value attribute from the submit button it returns nothing.